# Why I have an ElasticSearch percolate query error?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, dsl, elk, elasticsearch-percolate

When I am creating an index in ElasticSearch and trying to use percolate, I had an error that field with percolate type is not exists in index. But when I'm watching in index, field exists.

I will show you mapping, how doc is looks like in index, error and query bellow.

Please help me! I really am trying everything I can find in the Google.
Maybe someone knows what the problem.

Index Mapping:

```
    'index' => 'stop-words',
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [
            'number_of_shards' => 3,
            'number_of_replicas' => 2,
            'analysis' => [
                'analyzer' => [
                    'simple_punctuation_analyzer' => [
                        'type' => 'custom',
                        'tokenizer' => 'simple_punctuation_tokenizer',
                        'char_filter' => ['html_strip'],
                        'filter' => ['lowercase']
                    ]
                ],
                'tokenizer' => [
                    'simple_punctuation_tokenizer' => [
                        'type' => 'char_group',
                        'tokenize_on_chars' => [
                            'whitespace',
                            ',',
                            '.',
                            '\'',
                            '"',
                            ':',
                            ';',
                            '?',
                            '!'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'mappings' => [
            'properties' => [
                'id' => [
                    'type' => 'long'
                ],
                'stop_word' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'analyzer' => 'simple_punctuation_analyzer',
                    'fields' => [
                        'keyword' => [
                            'type' => 'keyword'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'stop_query' => [
                    'type' => 'percolator'
                ],

                'status' => [
                    'type' => 'boolean'
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Doc in index:

```
 {
    "_index": "stop-words",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "id": 1,
      "stop_word": "asdasdasd",
      "stop_query": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "stop_word": {
            "query": "asdasdasd",
            "analyzer": "simple_punctuation_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Error:

```
    Error: {"error":{"root_cause":
            [{"type":"query_shard_exception",
              "reason":"field [stop_query] does not exist",
              "index_uuid":"I9ZjvdjCQuyHylKTDicRRg",
              "index":"stop-words"}],
              "type":"search_phase_execution_exception",
              "reason":"all shards failed",
              "phase":"query",
              "grouped":true,
              "failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"stop-words",
                                "node":"PqSzl30DRnaNkFyp8RkOxg",
                                "reason":
                                   {"type":"query_shard_exception",
                                    "reason":"field [stop_query] does not exist",
                                    "index_uuid":"I9ZjvdjCQuyHylKTDicRRg",
                                    "index":"stop-words"}}]},"status":400}
```

My query:

```
            'index' => StopWord::STOP_WORDS_ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX_NAME,
            '_source' => ['id'],
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'filter' => [
                            ['term' => ['status' => true]],
                            ['percolate' => [
                                'field' => 'stop_query',
                                'documents' => $fields
                            ]]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
```

Comment: Please show the mapping you  get when running `GET stop-words` in Kibana Dev Tools

Comment: yeah, it was a problem with mapping

Comment: Cool glad you found out, then you can add an answer which might help other people.

Comment: Ok, i will try to describe the answer as i can.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the index mapping.
I have different functions for creating an index.
And one of this functions is using template of index with mapping, another is not.
So I had a problem with function that creating an index without mapping.
Than I insert document in index, and ES creating his own mapping of the field that must be percolate.

That's why I had an error when trying to use a field as a percolate.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out